# Multiply fine tuning with a thinspace \,

Tags: programming

What I want is a redefinition of command `\,` to the version `\,[N]` for given integer N

```
\, % standard usage
\,[2] % the same as \,\,
\,[3] % the same as \,\,\,
```

and so on

The usage of `\hspace` instead of the above is not quite comfortable

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Whenever you feel like using multiple `\,` commands, you should ask yourself whether you're doing the right thing.

Comment: Yes, I really understand what I want. When fine tuning spaces in math the usage like \,\,\,\, or\hspace{...} is ugly or very cumbersome. The code is hardly read. This is why I want to have simplified usage like \,[4]. No need new commands. There are analogous redefinition of codes for \ldots[N] on this cite somewhere, but I was not able to modify them for my needs.

Comment: If you are needing that much fine spacing then something is wrong elsewhere, if you do need more what is wrong with the existing `\,`, `\>`, `\;` thin medium and thick muskip respectively,

Answer (score 7):

Excessive manual spacing is usually a sign that something is going wrong; there is ***very rarely*** a need for changing the automatic spacing in math mode, and `\hspace` is the right tool in text mode. TeX has internal rules for spacing in math that have been distilled from decades (even centuries) of experience; do you?

This said, you can easily redefine `\,` as you like, but remember that your output will most likely be typographically disputable.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\,}[1][1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \mskip #1\thinmuskip
  \else
    \thinspace[#1]%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\thinspace}[1][1]{%
  \kern#1\dimexpr0.16667em\relax
}

\begin{document}

$a\,b$---a\,b

$a\,[1]b$---a\,[1]b

$a\,[1.5]b$---a\,[1.5]b

$a\,[2]b$---a\,[2]b

$a\,[2.5]b$---a\,[2.5]b

$a\,[3]b$---a\,[3]b

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, with the kernel `\newcommand` there will be problems in cases such as

```
A\, [p,q]
```

(but I'm asking why manually spacing here). This can be solved by doing the redefinitions using `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\,}{O{1}}{%
  \ifmmode
    \mskip #1\thinmuskip
  \else
    \thinspace[#1]%
  \fi
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\thinspace}{O{1}}{%
  \kern#1\dimexpr0.16667em\relax
}
```

Remember to leave a space if a bracket (not for the optional argument) follows.

Comment: I like this solution very much! Excellent. Thanks

Comment: By the way, egreg. Is it possible to improve your code for the following situations? Let I need to type $A \, [p,q]$. This new version of \, will face on bad "p" after "[" since it expects to have here some integer. In short, if a space follows by \, then let TeX understand this as \,[1].

Comment: @maximav I added how to cope with the problem. But I insist that this approach with manual spacing is wrong to begin with.

Comment: Dear egreg, thanks again for an updated code. It works fine but I watched it and observed that code of \, is heavy and strongly  complicated (under xparse). So I'd prefer to use your previous version which is very nice, small and speedy. Concerning the usage of new \,...

Comment: Of course, $A\, [$ is not the place where one needs to exploit it but many people, when typesetting, face frequently on a problem of the quick and instant fine tuning some tiny spaces (TeX does not do all things in universal and ideal way). They do not want to study any TeX's internals/commands etc. They merely want to watch here, right here(!) and right now(!) exactly those spaces they wish to have. I myself and, think, other users know only simple commands \, and \! and nothing know and want know any more.

Comment: I used the xparse version to make all thin spaces breaking.

Answer (score 3):

If fine-tuning the horizontal placement of math atoms and molecules is the objective, why stick with `\thinspace` as the basic unit? In mathmode, thinspace is equal to `3mu`, where `18 mu = 1 em`. You may well need finer control than `3mu`. For ultimate control over placement, use statements such as `\mkern3.8mu` and `\mkern12.9mu`. Of course, one finds that `\,\,\,` is the same as `\mkern9mu`. (You have probably already guessed that `\mkern` is short for "math kern".)

Answer (score 2):

The TexBook definition of `\,` is: `\def\,{\mskip\thinmuskip}`

You could do the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\myThinspace[1]{\mskip #1\thinmuskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    AB                  \\
    A\,B                \\
    A\myThinspace{20} B
\end{align}  

\end{document}
```

[image: example]